# storing the data entered in a text file using perl cgi?

Tags: perl

I have installed a boa server on my arm. and now i am writing a cgi script where i can get some data from user( on some other Pc but on the same network ) and save it in a text file in my arm.

Here is my CGI file, to store the data in a text file i need to use the  "USE CGI" to get the data entered but when i uncomment it on this code i get error 502 Bad gateway  The CGI was not CGI/1.1 compliant. Need Help!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
#use CGI;
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
#open (MYFILE, '>>guestbook.txt');
#  print MYFILE "1111111\n";
# close (MYFILE);
print <<"EOF";
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Hello, world!</TITLE>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
function copyText()
{
document.getElementById("field2").value=document.getElementById("field1").value;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
}
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>Hello,</H1>
Enter Email Address: <input type="text" id="field1" value="Hello1 World!"><br>
Field2: <input type="text" id="field2">
<br><br>
<button onclick="copyText()">Copy Text</button>
</BODY>
</HTML>
EOF
```

Comment: Are there any messages in your error log when this happens?

Answer (score 0):

> 502 Bad gateway The CGI was not CGI/1.1 compliant

Usually this error comes due to permissions. Try to add read and execute access rights to others.

```
chmod o+rx yourscript.cgi
```

Comment: The rights of my CGI file are correct. just by adding "USE CGI" gives me the bad gateway error

Answer (score 0):

Check the text of your cgi script to see whether it uses unix line endings "\n" or dos/windows line endings "\r\n".

You can do this from the shell:

```
 $ od -c mycgiscript.pl
```

If you find your file riddled with windows line endings, then to this:

```
 $ tr -d '\r' mycgiscript.pl > /tmp/mycgiscript.pl
 $ cp /tmp/mycgiscript.pl mycgiscript.pl
 $ rm  /tmp/mycgiscript.pl
```

Make sure read/execute bits don't get reset, and the try running your script again.

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou so much AKHolland , actually i checked the error logs and figured out that some of my perl modules were missing. Now it's working!